# How to check where the input word lies in terms of word range?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

How to check whether input word lies "before", "inside", or "after" a given "word range"? For each input word, we just need to output `"before", "inside" or "after"`..

To determine the order, character precedence rule is: `'' < 'A' < 'a' < 'B' < 'b' ..  'Z' < 'z'`.

```
Format of input is:
1) <start word> <end word>
2) A sequence of N words
```

For example:

```
Input:
============
Apple Pear
Aa
Aq
App
Apple

Output:
============
before // as Aa < Apple
inside // as Aq > Apple && Aq < Pear
before // as App < Apple
inside // as Apple == Apple && Apple < Pear
```

Below is what I have got but it gives wrong output so my comparison logic is wrong looks like.

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String startWord =  sc.next(); // this will give "Apple"
    String endWord =  sc.next(); // this will give "Pear"
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
       // below will give "Aa", or "Aq", or "App" or "Apple" one by one
        String queryWord =  sc.next();
        if(queryWord.compareTo(startWord) < 0 && queryWord.compareTo(endWord) < 0) {
            System.out.println("before");
        } else if(queryWord.compareTo(startWord) > 0 && queryWord.compareTo(endWord) > 0) {
            System.out.println("after");
        } else if(queryWord.compareTo(startWord) == 0 && queryWord.compareTo(endWord) == 0) {
            System.out.println("inside");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}

Update:
```

So logic will be this?

```
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String queryWord =  sc.next();
        int qValue = 0;
        for(char c : queryWord.toCharArray()) {
            qValue += map.get(c);
        }
        if(qValue > sValue && qValue < eValue) {
            System.out.println("inside");
        } else if(qValue > sValue && qValue > eValue) {
            System.out.println("before");
        } else {
            System.out.println("after");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a question before posting a solution, the input data will only contain capital letters from A to Z and small letters from a to z.

Comment: Yes it will only have those letters.

Comment: Last check looks bogus. `compareTo` should only return 0 if they are the same. You have to check that it is bigger than start and smaller than end.

Comment: Look at your last if: you want to say the the queryWord >= startWord and queryWord <= endWord.

Comment: Also, note that you are assuming that startWord < endWord. You could make sure by comparing them too.

Comment: I am confuse so what should be the correct logic for this then?

Comment: @john `"' < 'A' < 'a' < 'B' < 'b' ..  'Z' < 'z'`, is this your custom rule for this particular program or do you assume it works this way?

Comment: its custom rule for this program

Answer (score 0):

Before posting a solution, let's take a look at the input range.

each letter of the word will be anything inside of [A,Z] or [a-z].

Now below is the logic that I would like to use in order to calculate whether a given input is - `before`, `inside` or `outside`.

```
1. Let's initialize two variables - startWord and endWord.
2. Take input for the above two variables.
3. Now, I create a map which stores value for each letter constant. As per the question, my values will look something like this:-
   A - 1
   a - 2
   B - 3
   b - 4
   .
   .
   Z = 51
   z = 52.
4. Now I will calculate value of each word, so for example, value of Apple will be = A+p+p+l+e = 1+32+32+24+10 = 99.
5. Similarly I will do for Pear.
6. Now for each user input value, for example Aa. I will make this calculation again, so for Aa its = A+a = 1+2 = 3. And 3 is less then 99. 
7. Now it all comes to Maths, if this value is within the range of startWord and endWord, then I print inside, if its less then answer is before otherwise after.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated my question. Will the logic be like that?

Comment: Hey @john it should work for sure. I will code it later in the day to test it. Also for inside logic, use if(qValue >= sValue && qValue <= eValue) { //inside condition}

Answer (score 0):

let us assume it as a number line in which firstword is at point X and and secondword is at y.

As per the question we need to state that the input word lies below x, in between x and y or its beyond y.

---

Now, the question arises that how the comparison will happen for different words ?

*seeing the above example, we can conclude that if  the any character of the first string if bigger than the character at the same position of the other string, then we can say that first string is bigger than than other.*
For example:

1. Aa < Apple - because the 2nd 'A' in 'AA' will lie below 2nd 'p' in
   'Apple' in a number line .
2. Aq > Apple - because the 2nd 'q' in 'Aq' will lie beyond 2nd 'p' in
   'Apple' in a number line.
3. App < Apple - because 'App' is equal to 'App' in 'Apple' but it has
   extra 2 more characters 'le' after 'App'.

   public static void main(String args[]) {

   ```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String startWord = sc.next(); // this will give "Apple"
   String endWord = sc.next(); // this will give "Pear"

   while (sc.hasNext()) {
       String queryWord = sc.next();

       if (compare_str(queryWord, startWord) < 0 && compare_str(queryWord, endWord) < 0) {
           System.out.println("before");
       } else if (compare_str(queryWord, startWord) > 0 && compare_str(queryWord, endWord) > 0) {
           System.out.println("after");
       } else if (compare_str(queryWord, startWord) >= 0 && compare_str(queryWord, endWord) <= 0) {
           System.out.println("inside");
       }
   }

   sc.close();
   ```

   }

I designed a custom compare function which compare the string and returns the status on as 1,0,-1.

```
public static int compare_str(String a, String b) {
    int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i))
            continue;
        if ((a.charAt(i) > b.charAt(i)))
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    if (b.length() > a.length())
        return -1;
    if (b.length() < a.length())
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this piece of code will be usefull.